# reading and decoding .dat file with python

Tags: python

I have a .dat file which I don't have any idea about how it was created and what delimiter was used and any details about it.

i tryied this:

```
infile = open('x.dat', 'r')
for line in infile:
    variable, value = line.split('=')
    variable = variable.strip()
infile.close()
```

but i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gbcdev/py/read_dat.py", line 2, in <module>
    for line in infile:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
```

I would first like to understand what is in this .dat file and then change it
can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried to just open it and read it with a text editor?

Comment: @Ben yes, unsuccessfully

Comment: There is no known standard on what belongs to a .dat file, its type of encoding or if it's text or binary. First make sure that you know what kind of file you're dealing with.  If you don't have access to the program that created that .dat file's source code it can be hard or impossible to decode.

Comment: o tipo de codificação é binário.